# How do I get the innerHTML of an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, innerhtml

I have a big big trouble. :( I'm trying to get an iFrame innerHTML in order to put that in a div innerHTML. I've tried everything I found on google. Is there any chance to help me with that? Thanks!

Comment: Does the site in the `iframe` have the same domain and port as the parent document?

Comment: Yes, they have. What I am trying to do is to load page2.html or page2.php into a div from index.php.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show some example code of what is not working.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is the site in the `iframe` does not have the same domain, protocol and port as its parent, and therefore, can not be accessed.

This is by design. Check out the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

If you are on `http://sub.domain.com` and want to access `http://domain.com`, you could use...

```
document.domain = 'domain.com';
```

[Documentation @ MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.domain).

As for getting the `innerHTML`, try...

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe'),
    iframeDocument;

if ('contentWindow' in iframe) {
   iframeDocument = iframe.contentWindow;
} else {
   iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument;
}

var innerHTML = iframeDocument.innerHTML;
```